# Angular Material: 'md-card-title-text' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

using Angular v5 with Angular Material v5.

markup:

```
  <md-card md-theme="'dark-blue'" md-theme-watch>
    <md-card-title>
       <md-card-title-text>
```

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'md-card-title-text' is not a
>   known element:
>   1. If 'md-card-title-text' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

my module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatIconModule, MatMenuModule, MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, 
      MatMenuModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatCardModule
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

the other Material elements on my page work fine. md-card parses fine after I added MatCardModule.

what's perplexing is why adding MatCardModule worked to fix any md-card issues, but not md-card-title-text

Answer (score 1):

Because in Material@5, the element is called

```
mat-card
```

They renamed all of their components.

Comment: looks like their reference is outdated https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/card
i tried simply renaming to md- to mat- but that's still breaks in places.. is there no up to date reference? if i have to hack to get every component to work it's not using this framework ...

Comment: This example from official repo : https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/5.0.x/src/material-examples/card-fancy helped me